# int pointer type casting fails

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

This code fails compilation on both the MSVC compiler and gcc (MinGW).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

The compile error is

> Error C2440 'initializing': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'int *'

Of course, changing the allocation line to

```
int *a = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

makes compilation possible. **Why is an explicit type cast required?** When I allocate other kinds of data (like a `struct` or ), there's no problem with this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using C++ compiler, it may be caused by using wrong extension (`.cpp`)

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

is valid in C. There is an implicit conversion from any object pointer type to `void *`.

In C++ it is not valid (Because its stronger typed that C), there is no such implicit conversion, and you need a cast:

```
int *a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
int *a = static_cast<int*>(malloc(sizeof(int));
```

If you are using C++, you can/should use `new` and `delete` operators.

```
int *a = new int();
delete a;
```

Comment: The name of a programming language is not code, so please do not format it as if it were.

Comment: Sir, yes sir !.

Answer (score 2):

Either you named your file wrong or you are using the wrong compiler.

If your file has a *.cpp* or *.cxx* extension change it to *.c*, otherwise ensure that the compiler is a c compiler and not a c++ one.

In c++ the explicit cast is needed, in fact it would look something like

```
int *a = static_cast<int *>(malloc(sizeof(int));
```

and that would never compile with a [c](/questions/tagged/c) compiler.

Comment: I indeed used an `.cpp` extension by accident. Thank you!

Comment: @WardSegers Some IDEs assume that you will never code c code, some are specifically c++ IDEs so it's probably not your fault.